# How to include both precedence and associativity in following grammar?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, compilers

For the following grammar, how can I include both precedence and associativity of operators:

> S -> S|S
>
> S -> S.S
>
> S -> S*
>
> S -> (S)
>
> S -> a|b

**Note**: In the first rule `S -> S|S`, the symbol `|` is the OR symbol and not two rules.

Here, operators are `|`, `.`, `*` and `()`.

PS: Suppose the precedence order is : () > * > . > |. And all are left associative.

Comment: But you did not tell us what precendence and associativity you want.

Comment: Suppose the precedence order is : () > * > . > |. And all are left associative.

Comment: Why don't you give it a try? Consult any algebraic grammar for reference. See, for example, http://users.monash.edu/~lloyd/tildeProgLang/Grammar/Arith-Exp/ or http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~fischer/cs536.s08/course.hold/html/NOTES/3.CFG.html (Google search found me at least dozens of study guides; I chose those two because they were on the first page of results and not PDFs).

Comment: You mention "compilers", there the task of managing precedence/associativity is normally handled by the parser generator (bison, ply come with detailed examples, there are many others), or if the parser is hand-written, a technique like Hanson's ["Compact recursive-descent parsing of expressions"](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/spe.4380151206) is used instead.